# How to export Charts to PDF with jsPDF in Chart JS

Tags: html, charts, chart.js, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to download the bar graph to pdf but is not working.
trying to download the bar chart to pdf. the chart since to give me a lot of issues.
the java script for the graph, I have tried but did not avail, please can someone help me out

```html
<div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Bar Chart</h2>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="body" id="myChart">
                            <div class="sales-bars-chart" style="height: 320px;"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
const myChart = new chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
        );

    function downloadPDF(){
        const convas = document.getElementById('myChart');

        const canvasImage = convas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        console.log(canvasImage)
        let pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.setFontsize();
        pdf.setFontsize(20);
        pdf.addImage(canvasImage, 'jpeg', 15,15,280,150);
        pdf.save('salerecoed.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: The issue could be that the "myChart" is NOT a canvas but a DIV.  Here is a codepen where is working: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/OJENbwM

Comment: Thanks so much but after downloading, the graph has a dark background. can you help out, please

Comment: A plugin to color the cnbas as background is needed. See CHART.JS doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/canvas-background.html I'll update the answer adding background color plugin

Answer (score 1):

Here is the codepen with a working sample. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/OJENbwM

An additional plugin is needed to color the background of the canvas, as reported in CHARt.JS doc https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/canvas-background.html:

```
const plugin = {
  id: 'custom_canvas_background_color',
  beforeDraw: (chart) => {
    const {ctx} = chart;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
};
```

The plugin must be added to chart configuration, as following:

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [plugin], // <<--- adds plugin to color the background of the canvas
  data: chartData
});
```